# How to do load testing for a web application built using JSON restful web service at server side?

Tags: web-services, rest, testing, performance-testing, load-testing

this question is not about which tools to use to do load testing ...

It is a more general question about what should be tested.

background:

years ago, most enterprise web application used to be designed that front end and backend are messed together, and any kinds of business logic is done at server side. while front end's responsibility is only to show the UI.

when load testing such application, whether it is Oracle EBS or SAP's things, or application built using framework like Struts.

What we do is to:
 1. design a user test case. (like login, search , put sth to shopping car, then check log)
 2. write testing script to archive such test case (underline, it's pure http call to server side )
 3. using LT tool to generate lots of virtual user together to run such test. 
(it will just behave like that there are lots of  user do the same business logic together)

While now , the whole thing changed after  after front end and backend totally separated.

Lot of business logic can be put in front end, and server end only has separate restful web service...

What i found is that we can't do load testing like before.

Just because user's test case can't be mapped to http communication.  As some task is totally done in front end...

BUT in such new world, how to do performance testing?  Just performance test the JSON restful web service? How about the static resource transferred from service side to browser ?

I need suggestions from these who done lot of performance/load testing for such JSON restful web service application..

Answer (score 1):

Your load testing should not be limited to backend only. Well-behaved load test needs to represent real user sitting behind real browser as close as possible including (but not limited to):

- [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) like User-Agent which identifies the browser, Accept-Encoding which is used for content compression, etc.
- [HTTP Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) which are being used for authentication purposes and tracking user session
- [Caching mechanisms](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/browser-cache-makeuseof-explains/) - browsers use to download images, scripts and styles which are embedded in the webpage and store them locally so on subsequent requests these "heavy" entities won't be re-downloaded but rather returned from browser's disk cache
- [AJAX requests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) which are asynchronous JavaScript-driven calls which are being used for updating page content on the fly without reloading the full page. The tricky point is that AJAX requests are being executed in parallel (i.e. one main requests "spawns" several parallel AJAX requests) and the majority of load testing tools cannot handle this situation

So your test target needs to be **frontend**, not the backend as backend-only testing doesn't tell the full story and you can miss something important. See [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article for more detailed explanation and example configuration applicable to [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) free and open source load testing tool (however the approach should be tool-agnostic, you should follow the same steps no matter of what load testing tool is being used under the hood)

Comment: I understand everything you mean, I know tools (in fact, we build much much more complex and advanced tools than JMeter, for example, support parallel AJAX from tool itself...).  BUT the problem is that lots of business logic is done at client side now (using JS function from front end, most are  in encrypt JS ), which makes it impossible to represent "real user " for load testing.  What i am thinking now, traditionally load testing just doesn't exists for application has a rich client side.  And the only way to load testing server is to test the server exposed API(most are restful web service

Comment: I need some best practice for real load testing application which has  JSON restful web service backend , and lots of business logic put at front end. (for example, some search /filter are done in front end...)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it gets harder to test "realistic" traffic patterns with rich clients. It is also the case that as more things move onto the client side, scalability testing becomes more about testing the backend API.

Like Dmitry writes, testing the whole content delivery system is always useful, but given the choice between testing your own API and the CDN that delivers your images, I'd say that testing the API is much more important. That is where you'll most likely find scalability issues.

We have realized that a reason many don't load test at all is because it is simply "too much work" and requirements for realistic testing are a major contributing factor to this. We've written a "developer-centric load testing" manifesto, soon to be released, that argues that "Simple tests are better than no tests at all". May seem obvious, but still most people don't load test at all today. For this reason, we advocate starting out very simple, with small "unit load tests" that hit a single API end point. Write a couple of those really simple tests and start running them regularly (ideally in nightly builds on a CI system), just exercising API end points individually and see how many requests per second (or whatever metrics you want to measure) they can take.

These simple tests *are* going to provide you with a lot of value for little effort - the 80/20 rule in action. They test the most relevant parts of the whole system, and any smoke you see coming out as a result of this testing will likely tell you where your system is going to blow up when put under "real" (as in "realistic") pressure. You should also be able to detect most performance regressions as an added bonus. Finally, these small "unit load tests" are easier to maintain due to their simplicity; they don't get obsolete as fast as a complex/realistic test does, and if they do, they're easier to update.

When you have a "unit load test" test suite that provides value, you can add complexity and realism iteratively as you go, until the ROI on your time spent becomes too low to motivate any further effort. There is really no difference between this approach and the standard approach for building a regular unit test suite.

Comment: Thanks Ragnar,  the idea of unit level simple load testing, which can be integrated into CI system seems good.  Especially for 80% cases...     
   Leave the question open now to see if there are more insight from others.